# ConnectionClosedException when reading data from HBase running inside docker

Tags: docker, hbase, hbase-client

I have HBase running in docker. I can connect using the shaded client and perform getClusterMetrics() and get the table descriptor.
However, when I try reading data from the table using either get or scan, I get this exception

```
543935 [ReadOnlyZKClient-hbase:2181@0x687080dc-SendThread(kubernetes.docker.internal:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Reading reply sessionid:0x16ed32515ad001d, packet:: clientPath:/hbase serverPath:/hbase finished:false header:: 259,8  replyHeader:: 259,135,0  request:: '/hbase,F  response:: v{'meta-region-server,'rs,'splitWAL,'backup-masters,'table-lock,'flush-table-proc,'master-maintenance,'online-snapshot,'master,'switch,'running,'draining,'namespace,'hbaseid,'table} 

543935 [ReadOnlyZKClient-hbase:2181@0x687080dc-SendThread(kubernetes.docker.internal:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x16ed32515ad001d after 2ms

543938 [ReadOnlyZKClient-hbase:2181@0x687080dc-SendThread(kubernetes.docker.internal:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Reading reply sessionid:0x16ed32515ad001d, packet:: clientPath:/hbase/meta-region-server serverPath:/hbase/meta-region-server finished:false header:: 260,4  replyHeader:: 260,135,0  request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response:: #ffffffff000146d61737465723a3136303030ffffffe9ffffffa25fffffffe1135effffffa8ffffffe450425546a11a5686261736510ffffff947d18ffffffb9ffffffc6ffffff94ffffff99ffffffed2d100183,s{34,35,1575500467238,1575500468433,1,0,0,0,52,0,34} 

543944 [hconnection-0x23986957-metaLookup-shared--pool5-t11] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl  - Call exception, tries=8, retries=16, started=18351 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=Call to hbase/127.0.0.1:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed, details=row 'janusgraph,configuration,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hbase,16020,1575500456761, seqNum=-1, see https://s.apache.org/timeout, exception=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to hbase/127.0.0.1:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
```

The master log contains these warnings: (EDIT: These seem to be irrelevant)

```
2019-12-05 00:47:26,780 WARN  [qtp1634411546-76] http.HttpParser: Illegal character 0x0 in state=METHOD for buffer HeapByteBuffer@253d3e6[p=5,l=348,c=8192,r=343]={HBas\x00<<<P\x00\x00\x00\xF8\n\n\n\x08nialeksi...\x00\x10\xFf\xFf\xFf\xFf\xFf\xFf\xFf\xFf0\x018\x01>>>kie: JSESSIONID=1...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
2019-12-05 00:47:26,780 WARN  [qtp1634411546-76] http.HttpParser: bad HTTP parsed: 400 Illegal character 0x0 for HttpChannelOverHttp@1cee436c{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
```

HBase Version is 2.2.2 and Shaded client is 2.2.2 as well.

**EDIT:**
Executing the client program inside the HBase container works fine, which means that this is some kind of connectivity issue. Inside my etc/hosts, I do have both hbase and hadoop pointed to 127.0.0.1